# jquery datatables export rows by class

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

create a custom export to get rows which have a certain attribute. In this case the cell 'Payment method' should contain 'check' (I can of course apply a data-attr or class to the cell or row).

What I found so far is to extend the button that way:

```
"buttons": [

                    { 
                        extend: 'pdf', 
                        text: '<i class="sm-close"></i>',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: [ 0, 1],
                            modifier: {
                                selected: true
                            }
                        },
                    },         
],
```

But that only works for selected rows, which is not what I'm looking for. I lost myself in the very (too) complete documentation of datatables.net... did anyone achieve that already ?

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction !

Answer (score 3):

You can pass selector to `rows` option, see [`buttons.exportData()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons.exportData%28%29) API method and [`row-selector`](https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector), if you could add certain class to the `tr` element.

For example, the following code will export all rows having class `row-checked`:

```
"buttons": [
   { 
      extend: 'pdf', 
      text: '<i class="sm-close"></i>',
      exportOptions: {
         rows: '.row-checked', 
         columns: [ 0, 1]
      }
   }
],
```

You can also use function for `rows` option and use jQuery selector to determine if cell has certain attributes.

For example, the following code will select a row if it has a cell with element having class `check`:

```
"buttons": [
   { 
      extend: 'pdf', 
      text: '<i class="sm-close"></i>',
      exportOptions: {
         rows: function ( idx, data, node ) {
            return ($('td .check', node).length) 
               ? true 
               : false;
         },
         columns: [ 0, 1]
      }
   }
],
```